# print op(0, expr) without proc()

Tags: maple

If I do this

```
z:=factor(randpoly(x)): 
op(0,z);
```

then I get nice result `+` (or `*` or `^` when polynomial z is reducible over **Q**).
But if I do this

```
for i from 1 to 1 do
  z:=factor(randpoly(x)):
  print(op(0,z));
end do:
```

then I see this

```
proc () option builtin = `+`; end proc
```

Is there a way to print just the `+`, i. e. without `proc()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing `print` of the assigned value of the global name `+`.

You could instead use the following (which also prints it as an unevaluated name),

```
print(convert(op(0,z),`local`));
```

or,

```
print(convert(op(0,z),string))
```